# C++ preprocessor for creating string literals

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I need to do something like:

```
#define charSz 16

#if charSz == 8
    typedef char8_t Char;
    #define STR(s) #s
#elif charSz == 16
    typedef char16_t Char;
    #define STR(s) u ## #s
#elif charSz == 32
    typedef char32_t Char;
    #define STR(s) U ## #s
#endif 

#include <string>
typedef std::basic_string< Char > String;

int main(){

  String s=STR(nice) ;
  String t=STR(very nice) ;
  String u=STR(good) ;

  return 0;

}
```

but the preprocessor issues

> allocator.cpp:24:21: error: pasting "u" and ""good"" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Comment: What version of `gcc` or `clang` are you using? Works for me on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: Also, what mode are you using? `u""` string literals are new in C++11, so naturally the code won't work in C++03 mode.

Comment: Looks like you're compiling with `g++` without giving the `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: @MattClarkson The version used is: g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Comment: @JosephMansfield . I compiled with -std=c++11 and it went OK !

Comment: Note that all this can be done *without* macros and with `constexpr` and templates – a far superior solution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In a compiler that supports `constexpr` properly, sure. Depends on how "portable" you'd like to be. But at least [MSVC does not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) in the most recent stable release.

Comment: @KonradRudolph How exactly should it had been done using constexpr and templates ?

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis It would be better to post a real SO question about `constexpr` and template instead of burying it within the comment section... After due diligence research, of course. ;)

Comment: @George Forget I said anything, I was jumping the gun there. Can’t be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `u""`/`U""` string literals are C++11 and later only and not supported in older versions of C++.

If your compiler supports C++11 and your project allows to use it, then enable C++11 compilation (e.g. g++ and clang++ using the `-std=c++11` switch).

Otherwise, you're out of luck. The older `L""` is not a proper substitute for UTF-16 strings, and there aren't any 32-bit wide string literals at all.